# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException CREATE TABLE

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, create-table

**com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax**

I have a `create_table(String table_name)` function. There seems to be an SQL syntax error that I'm not able to figure out. I found a lot of threads with similar questions and most of them were left unanswered. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

The complete stack trace:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1006 (Date VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, Weight FLOAT NOT NULL, Amount FLOAT NOT NULL, P' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2547)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1541)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2605)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1469)
at com.appsmith.card_io.IOstream.create_table(IOstream.java:249)
at com.appsmith.card_io.IOstream$1.actionPerformed(IOstream.java:110)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:676)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:674)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:673)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

The create table function:

```
public void create_table(String table_name) {
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append(String.format("CREATE TABLE %s ", table_name));
    sql.append("(Date VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, ");
    sql.append("Weight FLOAT NOT NULL, ");
    sql.append("Amount FLOAT NOT NULL, ");
    sql.append("PRIMARY KEY (Date))");
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql.toString()); //IOstream.java:249
    } catch (SQLException e) {          
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Date` may be reserved keyword in android, try changing to `Date_` and check once..

Comment: @ELITE Still getting the error

Comment: what is the table name?? Check answer.

Comment: Your table name is `1006`?  That is not a valid table name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.

Therefore either quote the table name or rename it to include a letter

```
sql.append(String.format("CREATE TABLE `%s` ", table_name));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Reimeus. This worked for me. I named my table as the ID. Replacing it with "T" + ID solved it.

Comment: yeah better to avoid using digits only and use intelligible table names (letters/words.....) :)

Comment: Having a table name with an ID in it, sounds like you are abusing tables to have a table per "parent record" instead of using foreign key constraints or something like that.